# Pronouncing Statements About Partial Orders

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

How are the following partial order statements pronounced? $a \preccurlyeq b$; $a \prec b$; and $a \preccurlyeq_D b$. To put the last one in context, $\preccurlyeq_D$ refers to a specific partial order in an example I was reading.

Comment: I've  heard people use "less than", "less than or equal", "less sub $D$ than", "less than or equal sub $D$", "less than or equal-$D$" or even "$D$-less than or equal" and "$D$-less than".

Comment: I have always said "$a$ precedes $b$" myself, adding "under $D$" if necessary

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Could there be confusion between $\preccurlyeq$ and <? Or does the distinction not matter?

Comment: @SortofDamocles "Precedes" is a nice way to phrase it, but how could $\preccurlyeq$ and $\prec$ be distinguished?

Comment: precedes and strictly precedes, I think

Comment: @CriticalAcumen, I think it depends on the context. If you also have a $<$ floating around, then it might. In that case I'd personally use "curved less than", "fancy less than" or any sort of identifier to make a distinction.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Ah ok, that makes sense.

Comment: @SortofDamocles I'm satisfied with that pronunciation then -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Precedes" for $\preccurlyeq$ and "stricly precedes" for $\prec$. Thank you @ShervinSorouri and @SortofDamocles for their help.